# How can I insert a formula in a cell?

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

How can I insert a formula in a cell in Automation Anywhere?

When I set the cell only with the value it throws me the following error:

[image]

I have the following:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing line 13 (Go to cell) and instead of line 16 and 17, use the 'Set cell' operation where the cell to be selected is `I(1+$Counter$)`. Not sure if the `1+$Counter$` gets interpreted as an integer, otherwise you can use a dummy variable for this which you increment in the loop itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set the current active cell using Set value and insert a function. Pretty annoying. I have used something like an offset transaction counter and offload your set value to like Z$vCounter$, store the value, and reassign it back to whatever cell you wanted to originally set the value of.

This is a very brief example
https://i.gyazo.com/de73a60d7f177a26c71cc2e01ed862a4.png

Comment: Please do not include images of code, as they are not accessible, not searchable, and are hard to read on small screens like phone screens. Instead paste the code into your answer and format it by indenting it by four spaces, or by using ctrl+k.

Comment: Hi Jason, you cannot just copy and paste Automation Anywhere code. Otherwise I would. I'd include the actual image in my comment if I had the rep. Just wanted to help OP. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is the semi-colon (;) in the formula. If this raised an error then it would leave cell I2 in edit-mode preventing typing in cell I3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keystrokes + go to cell , you can do it into a loop in order to use the counter of the loop